# Odoo 8 override button with workflow

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-8

I want to override the button 'Validate' inside Accounting -> Customer Invoices -> Invoice. I just want to change the visibility group (just for customer refunds).

Here is how it looks like:

```
<record id="invoice_form" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">account.invoice.form</field>
  <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_form"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="/form/header/button[@name='invoice_open' and @states='draft']" position="replace">

      <!-- Show validate button inside invoice of type out_refund only, if in state draft + group_customer_refund_manager -->
      <button name="invoice_open" type="object" string="Validate" class="oe_highlight"
            attrs="{'invisible': ['|',('type', '!=', 'out_refund'), ('state','not in',('draft',))]}"
            groups="account.group_customer_refund_manager"/>
      <!-- Show validate button inside invoice of type !out_refund if state in draft -->
      <button name="invoice_open" type="object" string="Validate" class="oe_highlight"
            attrs="{'invisible': ['|',('type', '=', 'out_refund'), '&amp;', ('type', '!=', 'out_refund'), ('state','not in',('draft',))]}"
            groups="base.group_user" />

    </xpath>

  </field>
```

The button is replaced, however the workflow 'invoice_open' seems to be unknown now. When clicking on the Button I receive the error message **AttributeError: 'account.invoice' object has no attribute 'invoice_open**

Can you help me fix this for Odoo8. (I tried it for Odoo10 already and it worked ...the only difference there was, that the button name was 'action_invoice_open' and it triggers a method in python instead of a workflow - but I need it for Odoo8)

The workflow is still visible in the settings menu ...
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found my mistake :) - as I also tried for Odoo 10 I used the wrong button type for Odoo8.

As a workflow is called, the button type must be `workflow` instead of `object`.

Maybe this helps someone else too to find their errors when receiving a similar error. Thanks.